# Crear un ejecutable a partir de un script en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

ya hice una pregunta similar pero no terminó dando resultados el usar cx_freeze. Así que cuál sería la mejor forma de crear un ejecutable a partir de un script en python? 
Uso python 3.6.5(32 bits)

Los imports:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import pygame,sys,os
import tkinter as tk
import configparser as cp
from pygame.locals import *
from numbers import Number
from tendo import singleton
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo suelo recomendar py2exe, pero tal vez pyInstaler te sirva:

1. [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)
2. [pyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Con py2exe puedes incluir las librerias que usas o dependencias de directorios. PyInstaller permite tambien ser usado en otros SO generando los ejecutables del propio SO en el que se ejecutan, no solo para windows.